# Need help finding the source of an Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, callstack

I have a problem with the below code. When `s.q.has('on')` is typed into the console, a max-stack error occurs.

I know this means it is looping to infinity kinda-thing but I've yet to isolate the problem.  This is undoubtedly due to the lack of knowledge of the tools I'm using.

Though I will eventually figure out what is happening, I would like your input on locating the problem.  This code is as small as I could crop it and still get the error.

```
var q=new function(){
    var u,q;
    q_set_proto();
    q=new function Q(){
        this.ex=q_exist;
        this.tf=q_true_false;
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this.__proto__,null);
    };
    $(document).ready(q_boot);
    console.warn(q);
    return q;
    function q_set_proto(){
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'q',{get:function(){
            var slf,slfCon,q,cat,i;
            slf=this;
            slfCon=this.constructor;
            if(slfCon==String || slfCon==Number)
                slf=slf.valueOf();
            q={
                get isStr(){return qp_isStr.call(slf)},
                get cons(){return qp_constructor.call(slf)},
            };
            if(slfCon==String){
                cat={
                    get trm(){return qp_string_trim.call(slf)},
                    has : function(a,b){return qp_string_has.call(slf,a,b)},
                };
            };
            if(cat)
                for(i in cat)
                    Object.defineProperty(q,i,
                        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(cat,i)
                    );
            return q;
        }});
    };
    function qp_isStr(){
        return this.q.cons==String;
    };
    function qp_constructor(){
        return this.constructor;
    };
    function qp_string_trim(){
        return this.q.trm;
    };
    function qp_string_has(px,py){
        if(!q.ex(px) || !px.q.isStr && !px.q.isAry)
            return null;
        if(q.ex(py))
            if(!py.q.isNum || py!=0 && py!=1)
                return null;
        var len,c,i;
        if(px.q.isStr){
            if(!px.q.trm)
                return null;
            return this.q.dex(px)>=0;
        };
        len=px.q.len;
        if(!len)
            return null;
        c=0;
        for(i in px){
            if(!px[i].q.isStr || !px[i].q.trm)
                return null;
            c+=q.tf(this.q.dex(px[i])>=0);
        };
        if(!q.ex(py))
            return c==len;
        if(!py)
            return c==0;
        return c>0;
        /******************************
        s = offer coffee only on monday

        s.q.has('on')
        s.q.has(['on','off'])       -   all
        s.q.has(['one','two'],0)    -   none
        s.q.has(['one','off'],1)    -   any
        /******************************/
    };
    function q_boot(){
        s='offer coffee only on monday';
        console.debug(s);
    };
    function q_exist(tgt){
        return (tgt!==null && tgt!==u);
    };
    function q_true_false(con,t,f){
        if(!q.ex(t)){
            t=1;f=0;
        };
        return (con) ? t:f;
    };
};
```

Comment: your code returns `InternalError: too much recursion` when `s.q.has('on')` is ran on firebug, indicating that the error occurs on line 45

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my bad!

```
function qp_string_trim(){
    return this.q.trm;
};
```

Should be:

```
function qp_string_trim(){
    return this.trim();
};
```

Sorry guys.  Did say I'd crack it eventually though...

Comment: What's with all the one letter variable names?

Comment: tell me, which would you prefer to type a billion times in your lifetime? `for(index in x){...}` or `for(i in x){...}`

Comment: The one that makes sense when I (or some other poor sod) has to go back and read it. Using `i`, `j`, `k`, for loops is convention, using single letters for other things typically isn't (x/y for a point being a counter example).

Comment: Point taken, but each person develops their own unique prospective on this convention.  I have developed my own specific set of extensions to this, where-as we both would rarely use `i` out of a loop, I would never use `u` as anything other than `undefined`. **"where I see Order, you see Chaos..."**.  I will consider this in future posts!